# How to support jedis cluster in java

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Hi can any one give me some links to find implementation of jedis cluster in java web application .currently i am using spring redistemplate but it seems clustering is not working so please provide any alternative to implement redis cluster with jedis.

Comment: Spring Data Redis with Cluster support should be released later this year. You cold take a look on the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/tree/issue/DATAREDIS-315 branch how cluster support is implemented and build an own `JedisConnectionFactory` to fill the gap until the release train hopper is released (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Hopper)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but i am not able to find any cluster implementation here(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/tree/issue/DATAREDIS-315).

Comment: Look at this implementation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/issue/DATAREDIS-315/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisClusterConnection.java

Comment: thanks. but currently i have one spring web services project which is production, so now i want to integrate this redis template in existing one,it has done successfully with single node but here they used griddle i don't know. i am thinks that it is better to go pure jedis.i need your suggestion

Comment: How can i get this artifact id or jar file

Comment: I fear, that you will have to checkout the code and publish yourself the artifact in your (local) maven repository. I assume there is no snapshot available.

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between redis cluster and sentinal

Comment: Redis Cluster = Sharding with the possibility of HA (Master-Slave), Redis Sentinel = Redis Master Discovery without Sharding, Master-Slave Failover (and the docs tell something about config management)

Comment: Hi i have build that spring project successfully and it generate jar and i have included that in project Factory method [public org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate, while getting connectionfactory: ERR unknown command 'SENTINEL'

Comment: The connection does not point to a Redis sentinel instance.

Comment: static final RedisSentinelConfiguration SENTINEL_CONFIG = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master("localhost")         .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 6379);  @Bean
     public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
         return new JedisConnectionFactory(SENTINEL_CONFIG);
     } above one is my config to get connectionfactory

Comment: Redis Sentinel usually runs at port 26379. Port 6379 is Redis Standalone.

Comment: k can you give the bit of code to try and cluster supported spring data jar.

Comment: I fear that you have to refer to the documentation.

Comment: Hi i have integrated success full but i am getting following exception while compiling All sentinels down, cannot determine where is master is running... jedis connection

Comment: hi i am getting same exception All sentinels down, cannot determine where is localhost master is running...but local host is running in my sytem

Comment: Check out the Redis Sentinel docs, contains a guide how to set up Redis Sentinel with monitored Standalone nodes: http://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Comment: hi i need to talk with you directly can you give me any id or my gmail id mobileone4133@gmail.com can you please ping me on this mail

Comment: Hi I have discussed with my aws admin to configure sentinels for master, if aws not supporting sentinels what other choice to do failover process (wat exactly sentinel do)

Comment: As i spoke with aws elastic cache tech team, he said aws will take care of failover responsibility. but now my aim is how to connect multiple nodes and get connection for read write

Comment: I assumed something like that AWS ElastiCache handles all the magic. So everything you need is a plain Redis connection without cluster and sentinel.

Comment: k but he is providing multiple end points, how can i connect. is i need to jedis connection factory. i mean how to connect multiple endpoints one for write and another one for read

Comment: I'm not sure. I fear, it's a static thing, and I guess that Jedis does not support such a thing. Lettuce does not support it as well, but it has at least a transparent reconnect mechanism and I'm thinking all the time about providing multiple endpoints for retry attempts.

Comment: i will give you hint AWS providing service to get active end points.

Comment: What about Jedis pool to handle multiple nodes bout how can i handle write for particular node read for particular node

Comment: You need two pools, one for writing one for reading. The pools point to different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Redisson](http://redisson.org) framework. It fully implements Redis cluster support (master/slave discovery and topology update) and provides much easier api for Redis.